# If item is already array, move to front?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My function stops videos with the same ID being added to the history, but how would I make it so instead instead it moves the video to the front.

So it essentially either re-orders the array to the last watched or adds the video to the array.

```
function watch(video) {
    if ($.grep(myhistory, function (item) {
        return item["id"] == video["id"];
    }).length == 0) {
        document.location.hash = "!track=" + video["id"];
        updateHistory(video);
    }
    updateFavourite(video);

    $("#shareitlink").val("http://shuzel.com/#!track=" + video["id"]);
    document.title = "SHUZEL | " + video["title"];
    var html = "<b>{0}</b><br>by {1}<br>{2} | {3} views";
    $("#videoInfo").html(html.format(video["title"], video["uploader"], video["length"], video["views"]));
    ytplayer.loadVideoById(video["id"]);
    getRelated(video["id"], true);
    return false;
}

function updateHistory(video) {
    blacklist[video["id"]] = true;
    myhistory.push(video);
    var html = "<li class=\"saved\">" + "<img class= \"img-rounded\" src=\"{0}\"/>" + "<p><b title=\"{2}\"><a class=\"extendedLink\" href=\"javascript:watchHistoricVideo(\'{1}\');\"><span></span>{2}</a></b><br>" + "by {3}<br>" + "{4} | {5} views</p>" + "</li>";
    $("#myhistory").prepend(html.format(video["thumbnail"], video["id"], video["title"], video["uploader"], video["length"], video["views"]));
    setVideo(video);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll want to use `array.slice()`, `array.splice()` and `array.unshift()`.  Let us know if you have issues

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your array of movies, such as:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

You can check to see if the current movie is in the array, and if it is, `splice` it then `unshift` it to the front with something like:

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"],
    i = array.indexOf("three"),
    temp = array[i];
if (i > -1) {
    array.splice(i, 1);
    array.unshift(temp);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nUG82/)

Your code is awfully dense though, so it will be up to you to determine where to implement the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
// do whatever logic you have to get index of 
// array element to move to front. Using i=1 as example
var i = 1; 


// example array to affect
var array = ['a','b','c'];

// remove element i (2nd element) and add as first element
array.unshift(array.splice(i,1)[0]);

// array is now ['b','a','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

array.indexOf will tell you it item is in an array, returns the items index if in array and -1 otherwise.

indexOf is not available as a method for IE8 or ealier in which case add the following

```
if(!Array.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
            for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
                if(this[i]===obj){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

If not in array then as Crayon Violet suggests uses array.unshift to add to front of array.

If in array as Crayon Violet suggests uses array.slice(index,1) to remove item and array.unshift to add to front of array.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cj4Ub/

```
Array.prototype.addRecent = function(item){
    var index = this.indexOf(item);
    this.unshift(index > -1 ? this.splice(index, 1)[0] : item);
    return this;
};

alert([].addRecent("a").addRecent("b").addRecent("c").addRecent("b"));
```